# add_action not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am setting a WP that it should redirect all the request made to sub-directory to file inside that directory.
For example if there a visit on `example.com/link/me` then it should send the user to `/link/index.php?me`

To achieve this, I am trying to add rewrite rule in theme function file.
Here's what my code looks like:

```
function moin_add_rewrite_rules() {  
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        '^([^/]*)/(link)/(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)?$',  
        '/link/index.php?$matches[1]',  
        'top'  
    );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'moin_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

It is not working, visiting `example.com/link/me`shows a 404 (as link is outside WP).
Is there any problem with regex code? or anywhere else? What could be other possible solution?

Comment: doesnt look like you used `add_rewrite_tag` with your `add_rewrite_rule` you have to use the `add_rewrite_tag` to have it recognize your rewrites check it [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag). On a separate but related note rewrites can go into `.htaccess` which is a hidden file in your root dir just like Hobo referred.

Comment: @DavidChase I tried with `add_rewrite_tag` too but still getting 404. The think I want to mention again is, WP is in root directory but link directory is not WP. It's outside it.
And what would be the possible `.htaccess` code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the example in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), the matched expression doesn't have the leading `/`.

Stripping the leading bit out of your regex, then, I think this should work (sorry, I don't have a test environment handy):

```
add_rewrite_rule('^link/([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)/?$','/link/index.php?$matches[1]','top');
```

Alternatively, you could do something similar in your `.htaccess` file.

As a side note, I think as it's currently coded, you should be using `$matches[3]` not `$matches[1]`, as the value you're interested in is the third parameter in parentheses (the Codex notes "capture group data starts at 1, not 0").

Comment: it isn't working either. Also tried with `$matches[3]` :(
How can we do with .htaccess??